# In the pop-up menu, how to change the image source with changing pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, menu

I have the drop-down menu set in the page menu with 5 pages and their icons set, I would like that when I change the page, however, the icon of the page in which they are turned orange (I have already inserted the orange images in the project so that I have to change the source) but I can't get anything, any help?

This is how the menu is set up

```
public static List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    public MenuPage()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();

        menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Dashboard, Title="Dashboard", Source="Dashboard.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Anagrafica, Title="Anagrafica", Source="Anagrafica.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Marchi, Title="Marchi", Source="Marchi2.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Matrici, Title="Matrici", Source="Matrici.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Documenti, Title="Documenti", Source="Documenti.png"}
        };
```

Here is how I try to change the source of the selected page but to no avail

```
public Marchi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MenuPage.menuItems[2].Source = "marchiArancione";
```

But the first page that loads, the image manages to change it without problems, but if I set that if when it changes page it must return to the original one, nothing happens

Comment: Can you insert a breakpoint and see if the action gets called? Maybe you can try with `OnAppearing` instead of the constructor. Also does the image exist? I noticed that on the top code all images start on uppercase and ends with .png, but not the second code

Comment: Yes, the action is called, but it does nothing graphically.
I've never heard of OnAppearing, how can I use it?

Comment: All the classes that inherit from `Page` have [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page?view=xamarin-forms#methods) that can be overriden. `OnAppearing` gets called everytime the screen is shown, which can happen several times when switching between pages or when the app gets minimized. The same goes for `OnDIssapearing`. Your code is in the constructor, meaning that only will happen when the instance of the page is created

Comment: Question: how or when are you showing the `menuItems`?

Comment: MenuItems is the pop-up menu that opens if I click the three lines at the top left

Comment: And everytime you show the pop-up you build the UI from the content of `menuItem`? It's a little confusing. Maybe you should change the icon when the menuitem is clicked

Comment: Yes I know it is quite confusing, but I have to do all this because I also have a horizontal menu, and this procedure was good or bad for me to synchronize them

Comment: Ok, your problem is that probably the menuItem is never set to it's original value, because the constructor is not called again. That's why I said to move the code to the `OnAppearing`. This will make that when you go back to the `MenuPage`, the values will be set again